# Python PivotTable/Groupby Text Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I'm trying to broaden my python horizons and learn to do something that is fairly simple to execute in Excel.

I have this data:

```
Group   Function
1   A
1   B
1   C
2   A
2   C
3   C
3   A
3   D
4   E
```

And I would like to a table that shows the information in this format (accomplished with a pivot table in Excel with Columns: Function, Rows: Group, Values: Count of Group)

```
      Function
Group A        B       C    D    E
1     1        1       1    
2     1                1
3     1                1    1
4                                1
```

I've created a dataframe and added a column as below:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filepath)
df['1']=1

print(df.groupby('GROUP'))
```

but:

1) It's not recognizing the Function field because it's dtype: object
2) It's not really perfomring the function I'm looking for, which makes me think that it's probably not the function I need.  I've also tried to work various iterations of pivot_table but can't seem to get that to work etiher.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or using `pivot`

```
df1['val']=1
df1.pivot(index='Group', columns='Function')['val']

Function    A    B    C    D    E
Group                            
1         1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
2         1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
3         1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN
4         NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0


df1.pivot(index='Group', columns='Function')['val'].fillna(' ')

Function  A  B  C  D  E
Group                  
1         1  1  1      
2         1     1      
3         1     1  1   
4                     1
```

Or using `groupby` :

```
df1.groupby(['Group','Function']).size().unstack().fillna(' ')
Function  A  B  C  D  E
Group                  
1         1  1  1      
2         1     1      
3         1     1  1   
4                     1
```

Comment: @Tony , nice day

Comment: Pivot is nice, but crosstab is shorter imo :p. Still, nice job!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Agree ~ ,When count the size() crosstab is better

Answer (score 3):

How about `pd.crosstab`? Read in your data as is, and then transform:

```
In [227]: pd.crosstab(df.Group, df.Function)
Out[227]: 
Function  A  B  C  D  E
Group                  
1         1  1  1  0  0
2         1  0  1  0  0
3         1  0  1  1  0
4         0  0  0  0  1
```

Use `df.replace` to get rid of zeros:

```
In [228]: pd.crosstab(df.Group, df.Function).replace(0, '')
Out[228]: 
Function  A  B  C  D  E
Group                  
1         1  1  1      
2         1     1      
3         1     1  1   
4                     1
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is a great option!

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

```
pd.get_dummies(df.Group).T.dot(pd.get_dummies(df.Function))

   A  B  C  D  E
1  1  1  1  0  0
2  1  0  1  0  0
3  1  0  1  1  0
4  0  0  0  0  1
```

---

**Option 2**

```
i, r = pd.factorize(df.Group.values)
j, c = pd.factorize(df.Function.values)
a = np.zeros((r.size, c.size), dtype=int)
a[i, j] = 1
pd.DataFrame(a, r, c)

   A  B  C  D  E
1  1  1  1  0  0
2  1  0  1  0  0
3  1  0  1  1  0
4  0  0  0  0  1
```

---

**Opttion 3**

```
i, r = pd.factorize(df.Group.values)
j, c = pd.factorize(df.Function.values)
a = np.bincount(
    i * c.size + j, minlength=r.size * c.size
).reshape(r.size, c.size)
pd.DataFrame(a, r, c)

   A  B  C  D  E
1  1  1  1  0  0
2  1  0  1  0  0
3  1  0  1  1  0
4  0  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: pd.factorize... I would expect the usual suspects in one of your answers. Nice.

Comment: Thank you so much!